# Checkpointing in flink

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink

Trying to use checkpointing mechanism in flink with fs HDFS. 
While connecting with hdfs://aleksandar/0.0.0.0:50010/shared/ i get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /0.0.0.0:50010/shared/972dde22148f58ec9f266fb7bdfae891 from hdfs://aleksandar/0.0.0.0:50010/shared/972dde22148f58ec9f266fb7bdfae891 is not a valid DFS filename.
```

In the core-site settings i have the following configuration

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/var/lib/hadoop</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:123</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share how you set the check point configuration path.

Comment: Solved the problem by making the defaultFS 8020 and exposing that port too in the docker start up.